# SQL Server returning individual column from an inner join

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have the following SQL query:

```
select 
   * 
from 
   tbl_alert
inner join 
   tbl_IPAddress on tbl_IPAddress.ID = tbl_alert.IPAddressID
where
   tbl_alert.AlertType_ClassID = 124
   and tbl_ipaddress.ID = 4
   and DATEDIFF(minute, ISNULL((select max(scandatetime) 
                                from TBL_ScanQueue 
                                where IPAddress = tbl_ipaddress.IPAddress), GETDATE()), 0) < tbl_alert.Inactivity_Alert_Time
```

What I want it to do is return only the `displayname` from table `IPAddress`.

I have tried

```
select 
    Displayname 
from 
    tbl_IPAddress
inner join 
    tbl_IPAddress on tbl_IPAddress.ID = tbl_alert.IPAddressID
where
    tbl_alert.AlertType_ClassID = 124
    and tbl_ipaddress.ID = 4
    and DATEDIFF(minute, ISNULL((select max(scandatetime) 
                                 from TBL_ScanQueue 
                                 where IPAddress = tbl_ipaddress.IPAddress), GETDATE()), 0) < tbl_alert.Inactivity_Alert_Time
```

but it says some of the objects have the same exposed names.

I have tried everything I can think of but cant work this out

Comment: Instead of `select *` in your first query, replace with `select tbl_IPAddress.Displayname` ?

Comment: Why are you joining `tbl_IPAddress` to the same table `tbl_IPAddress` again in your second example?? Makes no sense at all ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT tbl_IPAddress.Displayname
FROM tbl_alert
INNER JOIN tbl_IPAddress 
ON tbl_IPAddress.ID = tbl_alert.IPAddressID
WHERE tbl_alert.AlertType_ClassID = 124
AND tbl_ipaddress.ID = 4
AND DATEDIFF(minute, ISNULL((select max(scandatetime) from TBL_ScanQueue where IPAddress = tbl_ipaddress.IPAddress), GETDATE()), 0) < tbl_alert.Inactivity_Alert_Time
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select Displayname 
from tbl_IPAddress
inner join tbl_alert on tbl_IPAddress.ID = tbl_alert.IPAddressID
where
tbl_alert.AlertType_ClassID = 124
and 
tbl_ipaddress.ID = 4
and
DATEDIFF(minute, ISNULL((select max(scandatetime) from TBL_ScanQueue where IPAddress = tbl_ipaddress.IPAddress), GETDATE()), 0) < tbl_alert.Inactivity_Alert_Time
```